# Troubleshooting formula to isolate root domain for competitor backlink analysis dataset in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subdomain

I've been following some [online tutorials](https://moz.com/blog/competitive-link-analysis-link-intersect-in-excel#link-intersect) and hit a roadblock with this complex formula below:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT([@[Target Subdomain]],LEN([@[Target Subdomain]])-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT([@[Target Subdomain]],LEN([@[Target Subdomain]])-LEN([@TLD])),".","|",LEN(LEFT([@[Target Subdomain]],LEN([@[Target Subdomain]])-LEN([@TLD])))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT([@[Target Subdomain]],LEN([@[Target Subdomain]])-LEN([@TLD])),".",""))))),[@[Target Subdomain]])
```

As I have a German MacBook, I substituted the "," for ";" but I still get an error message. Any thoughts on other issues that might be at play here or another way to isolate the root domain from the URL?

I ultimately want to be able to analyze intersects of domains with competitors so this is a roadblock for being able to count unique domains and having accurate data in the pivot tables I'm waiting to work on.

Comment: Try splitting it into smaller sections and checking the output from each...

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone.  @cybernetic.nomad the reformatting help worked perfectly--much appreciated.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad glad it is working now but i don't quite see what was wrong with  the original formula and different from the one you provided...is it possible to point it out as perhaps I just can't see the error given its so long? For my own edification...

Comment: hum, I only fixed the *format* of the formula in your post to make it easier for others to read. I did not change any of it. I cannot tell you why it is working now and didn't before...